# Writing mathematical expression in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, vegetation-index, boolean

I am trying to run the expression below in Google Earth Engine to calculate Index-base Built-up Index(IBI)

```js
var ibi = l8compositeMasked.expression(
    '(2*SWIR/(SWIR+NIR)-((NIR/(NIR+RED))+(GREEN/(GREEN+SWIR)))) / (2*SWIR/(SWIR+NIR)+((NIR/(NIR+RED))+(GREEN/(GREEN+SWIR))))', {
      'RED':l8compositeMasked.select('B3'),
      'GREEN':l8compositeMasked.select('B4'),
      'NIR':l8compositeMasked.select('B5'),
      'SWIR':l8compositeMasked.select('B6')
    });

Map.addLayer(ibi, {min:-1, max:1}, 'ibi', false);
```

but I keep getting the error below.

```
Layer shown property is not a boolean: ee.Image({
  "type": "Invocation",
  "arguments": {
    "DEFAULT_EXPRESSION_IMAGE": {
```

Below is the link to the script
https://code.earthengine.google.com/bdb6397411fe912861900cba04bb9172

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the last line of your script, not the line you have shown.

```js
Map.addLayer(ibi,{min:-1 , max:1},'UI', ibi)
```

Here the fourth argument should be a boolean but is the image `ibi`.

Answer (score 1):

Your last parameter in the Map.addLayer cal is the image again, not a name.
This line:

```
Map.addLayer(ibi,{min:-1 , max:1},'UI', ibi)
```

should be:

```
Map.addLayer(ibi,{min:-1 , max:1},'UI', 'ibi')
```